# Genymotion stuck on license agreement window

Tags: genymotion

I can't run the program, I've re-installed it multiple times and where the license agreement window *should* appear, there's **this black screen** every time:

[image]

If I close it, the program closes, so there's no way for me to use it at all. Don't know how to fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, eventually, that I was having troubles with the video drivers, since my computer is new and the SO had been installed recently.

I reinstalled these drivers, rebooted, and the Genymotion installation went fine from there.

Answer (score 4):

You can try a simple workaround:

When on the black window, make sure the window has focus, then:

- Press TAB twice
- Press SPACE
- Press TAB twice
- Press SPACE

This should click on the checkbox to accept the EULA then click on the validate button

(be aware that legally you just accepted an EULA without reading it...)

Let me know if it works :-)

Comment: This was clever and worked for a minute... since once I was able to run a virtual device, said VD appeared as a black window too.